# Android FB API 3.0 session setting with fragments

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using FB API 3.0 for Android, and I'm trying to set the session in proper way.

But, it seems I'm doing something wrong, or to say I'm missing something.

In my launcher activity, I check if there is a session already and if it does not exist I create new one (as in FB example):

```
Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehaviors.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null){
    String sesija = session.toString();
    Log.w ("ss", sesija);}

    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, MyGlobals.INSTANCE.statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            Log.w("No Session found", "Loading saved session as it exists");
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
            Log.w("No Session found", "CreatingNewSession");

            String sesija2 = session.toString();
            Log.w ("ss2", sesija2);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(MyGlobals.INSTANCE.statusCallback));
            Log.w("There is an active session", "Active Session Exists");
        }

    }
```

At this point my log says this:

```
10-24 09:11:52.284: W/ss(1404): {Session state:CREATED, token:{AccessToken token: permissions:[}, appId:xxxxxx}
```

(AppId is correct)

Then in my fragment, I try to log on to facebook using this code:

```
 Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
 if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            Log.w("Session is not opend", "Session is not closed");
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(getActivity()).setCallback(MyGlobals.INSTANCE.statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, MyGlobals.INSTANCE.statusCallback);
            Log.w("Open Active Session", "Status Callback");
        }
```

At this point, FB webview appears, I set username and pass, it kind a works, and then disappears.

Now, I'm sort of nowhere, I do not see response and TOKEN recived, and if I click again to login (on the same button) my App crashes.

In the log I have this then:

```
10-24 09:12:31.944: W/ss(1404): {Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token: permissions:[}, appId:xxxxxx}
```

If I compare it to SessionLoginExample provided by FB, I get there:

```
10-24 09:08:50.004: W/ss(1356): {Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:AAAFaKtb7Pg4BALYg4B5eosa0ZAE9ZAXB0ZBMFDJdNbsDsZAkGJUfKtGs71OEJikDxT2VBfo4QMXiNASz23ZAa6D76eUxW0mZAMa013HP2kxgZDZD permissions:[}, appId:xxxxxxx}
```

Meaning I'm doing something wrong, as I do not catch the returned AccessToken, and it is not saved properly.

That's what I think is wrong, but I do not understand how should I read the session information in proper way, or to say where to catch and save Token information within the fragment.

I tried to put in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Boolean session = Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getSherlockActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

As this was the "onActivityResult" in the example, but it seems that it does nothing.

Just to sum things up:
I create session behind the launcher activity. Then if there is no FB app installed, on Tab4 (settings) user should be able to log on to FB using webview. Then on Tab1 and Tab2 user should be able to Share image to FB similar like on Instagram.
If there is the app installed, I'd disable the tab 4, and let user share throuhg FB app using Tab1 and Tab2.

Tnx.

RESOLVED:
Thing that is never written but should be well known. When FB authentication is performed, the "On Activity Result" code must be executed to save the Token with the session. 
However, if you are dealing with Fragments and Tabs, like I do, function "onActivityResult" is never executed within Fragment code, but must be executed in the Activity that is taking care of fragments/tabs.

Comment: After onActivityResult you should be able to do everything you wish with fb api. Do you try any actions?

Comment: Yes, I've figured that out. Problem is that Fragments do not call "onActivityResult", but the main activity handling Tabs and fragments.

Comment: Yes, that's common problem about fragments. Great that it's working!

Comment: You can trigger the onActivityResult in your Fragment if you use the OpenRequest with a fragment constructor. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session.OpenRequest#Session.OpenRequest%28Fragment%29

Comment: Thanks your resolution i.e. Writing "On Activity Result" code in main tab activity instead of the activity which was calling it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

So it looks like you have already worked around this and your workaround is fine, but I wanted to give another option here in case it is cleaner for you or others to use the Fragment for this instead.

For cases where you cannot or do not want to derive from FacebookActivity, you can use either your Activity or your Fragment to initialize the Session.  Both Activity and Fragment have onActivityResult you can override, and the one that gets used depends on what you pass to initialize Session.OpenRequest.

So if you want the callback to come to the Fragment, you can call:

```
...new Session.OpenRequest(myFragment)...
```

Then override onActivityResult in your Fragment and forward the call to your Session.

This is somewhat nicer in that your Fragment no longer needs to have special knowledge of what Activity it is running in.

Comment: Tnx. I'll look into this option too if this is more appropriate, or at least to understand it better :)